# Better way to write before_save function to check all targeted attributes not blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

On my project, I have a model with four attibutes: name, desciption, content and completed.

I want to check all attributes except completed whether blank or not before save. If not blank, set completed to 1, otherwise, 0.

I use ActiveRecord and Mysql, so it would have id, created_at and updated_at columns also.

I wrote a before_save callback like this:

```
def check_completed
  if self.attributes.except("id", "created_at", "updated_at").all? {|k, v| v.present?}
    self.completed = 1
  else
    self.completed = 0
  end
end
```

It works, but it looks ugly. I want to remove the except function call.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Believe me, there are much uglier chunks of code. This one is fine. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the .except method was used because id, created_at, and updated_at are all internally generated and managed by MySQL.  So, it would be unusual for that list to expand or change.  I agree the code is good as provided.  If you wanted to shorten it at all, you could use a ternary as in:

```
def check_completed
  self.attributes.except("id", "created_at", "updated_at").all? {|k, v| v.present?} ? 1 : 0
end
```

Eliminating the .except method exposes you to managing this method any time the model changes.

Extending this discussion:
I am curious about your desire to return 1 or 0?  Not seeing more code, I am not sure of your intentions.  However, if a "before" callback returns false, execution is stopped and the transaction is rolled back.  In any other case, execution continues.  In Ruby, 0 is not false.  False is only triggered by either false or nil.  My expectation would be that it would be more likely to use true in place of 1 and false in place of 0?  if so, the code would be:

```
def check_completed
  self.attributes.except("id", "created_at", "updated_at").all? {|k, v| v.present?} ? true : false
end
```

Such that if any user attribute was not present, the transaction would be canceled and rolled back.  but, that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not relying on `self.attributes` since you may want to add additional attributes to your model in the future. If so, you'll have to add new attributes to your `except` list.

Instead you could do something like this:

```
self.completed = %w(name description content).all? { |attr| !send(attr).blank? } ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: Wow, cool. But if the model have more attributes to check, the array list also get longer, too. Maybe I should write a module to deal with it. Thank you for spelling correction.

Comment: Well yes it would. I'm assuming here it would stay reasonable. You might want to translate this into a method so you could do something like `self.completed = completable?`

Comment: Yeah, other models would use it too. And in some of them, more attributes should be excepted. So I'll try to write a class macro that I can use it as 'check_completed, :except => [:scale, :version]'.